# Resolving dependency

Tags: maven

** Please refer structure to relate with the issue described below. "=>" refers to depedency/classpath entries

I wanted to override a file say Test.java file inside the jar (say original.jar) by my customize file (with same name & package structure). For example Test.java file is available in original.jar as "org.sample.Test" and I have created a file with same name and package structure inside my project (say project "Depend") such as org.sample.Test in the src directory of the main project which is in the class path.

The depend project is consumed as jar (Depend.jar) by another project but this another project (say "Main" project) does not refer to my file checked in Depend project but rather refers file original.jar which is inside the depend.jar (as dependency). How should I resolve it.

I cannot use subclass to override Test.java file since all the methods are static.

---

Structure :-

Main Project => Depend.jar 
Depends.jar => Original.jar

---

-Original.jar has Test.java file which needs to be overridden
-Depends.jar also has Test.java file inside the same package structure as in Original.jar (org.sample)
- Main Project should refer Test.java that is checked in Depend project and not from Original.jar. Original will be referred by Depends project to use other classes from Original.jar except Test.java file

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand from your question.

There is `Original.jar` which contains `Test.java`
There is `Depend.jar` that depends on `Original.jar`. It also contains a `Test.java`
There is `Main.jar` that depends on `Depend.jar` (and `transitively`?) on `Original.jar`

We want `Main.jar` to use `Test.java` of `Depend.jar` and **not** of `Original.jar`

Here are a couple of ways to do this.

- If `Main.jar` does not need `Original.jar`, `exclude` `Original.jar` from the `dependency` declaration of `Depend.jar`
- **Repackage** `Original.jar` excluding `Test.java`.
- Create a [jar with dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) using [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin) of `Original.jar` and `Depend.jar`, in the process, excluding `Test.java` from `Original.jar`

Comment: Option 1- I cannnot remove Depend.jar as it has all the useful class used in Original.jar

Comment: Option 2- Repacking is not a good option in my case as it is third party package & we may use it new version as it is released

Comment: Option 3- exclusion is not possible as it is generated by tool i.e wsdl2Java. Acutally the stubs are created and their dependend java files are created to support the stub classes. I was wondering if it is possible to control how supporting classes are created by wsdl2java utility if we cannot resolve using maven dependency